# Insert Object At Index in Realm

Tags: objective-c, xcode, realm

Is it possible to add a Object to a realm at a specific Index. I want to add it at the index 0.
Thanks!

Comment: see this https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2149

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage objects in an order, you should use a to-many relationship on another class.

Given a model like that:

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)

@interface Queue : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Person *><Person> people;
@end
```

You could then insert a new person in front of the queue by using [`-[RLMArray insertObject:atIndex:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMArray(im)insertObject:atIndex:).

```
Queue *queue = [[Queue alloc] init];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
  [realm addObject:queue];
}];

[realm transactionWithBlock:^{  
  Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
  person.name = @"Tim";
  [queue.people insertObject:person atIndex:0];
}];
```